# Solving for $z$ in $\left((\frac{a}{b}+z)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)\right)-\left(z\Phi(z)+\phi(z)\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, normal-distribution

I'm encountering this specific function:

$$\left((\frac{a}{b}+z)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)\right)-\left(z\Phi(z)+\phi(z)\right)$$

, where $a$ and $b$ are given and $\Phi(\dots)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution:

$\Phi(x) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $

and $\phi(\dots)$ is the probability density function of the standard normal distribution:

$\phi(x) = \frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Now, $z$ is a function of $b, c$ and $x$, like:

$$z=\frac{y-c}{b}$$

, where $c$ is also a given, but $y$ is not.

Now, the two terms in $$\left((\frac{a}{b}+z)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)\right)-\left(z\Phi(z)+\phi(z)\right)$$

are both functions in the form of:

$$x\Phi(x)+\phi(x)$$ which are standard loss functions. From such a function, we can find $x$ because this conversion is standardized. So in the first term, $x$ is a function of $a, b, c$ and $y$, where in the second term, $x$ is a function of $b, c$ and $y$.

**Question**

I'm wondering if we could convert

$$\left((\frac{a}{b}+z)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)\right)-\left(z\Phi(z)+\phi(z)\right)$$

to a single loss function like

$$x\Phi(x)+\phi(x)$$

where $x$ is an arbitrary function of $y$ (and $a$, $b$ and $c$ *if* necessary). So it's not necessary to be a function of $a, b, c$ and $y$, but it *does* need to include $y$.

My goal is clearly to derive $y$ from

$$\left((\frac{a}{b}+z)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+z)\right)-\left(z\Phi(z)+\phi(z)\right)$$, so if there is another way to do this apart from the way I'm looking at, please feel free to comment on that as well.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\Phi(x)=\text P(z<x)$ and $\phi(x)=P(z=x)$. Maybe use probability formulas/properties to simplify?